# Button click is not redirecting to next page

Tags: android, android-layout

So, the problem I am facing over here is when I click on the login button it should redirect to the three_sections page but that is not happening. Same I did with the sign-in now but that worked. Clicking on the sign-in now button is redirecting me to the next page. But the login button is not! I have attached all the code below.

This is my **loginpage.xml** code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".loginpage"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="549dp"
        android:text="USER LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="205dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="449dp"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_foreground"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="393dp"
        android:hint="ENTER USERNAME" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="340dp"
        android:text="PASSWORD"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_foreground"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="284dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="273dp"
        android:hint="ENTER PASSWORD" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="163dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="188dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="525dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imaagee" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="408dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="292dp"
        android:src="@drawable/iimagee" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imagee" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
        android:src="@drawable/imageee" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signnow"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="143dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="SIGN IN NOW"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my **loginpage.java** class

```
public class loginpage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loginpage);

        TextView signnow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signnow);
        signnow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent p = new Intent(loginpage.this,new_user_register.class);
                startActivity(p);

            }
        });


        TextView login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(loginpage.this,three_sections.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is my **three_sections.xml** code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".three_sections"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="429dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@color/Purple" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="472dp"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text="     BEGINNERS CALLIGRAPHY"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="238dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@color/DeepPink" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:text="     ADVANCED CALLIGRAPHY"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="315dp"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=" INTERMEDIATE CALLIGRAPHY"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In your login page layout, signup and login are buttons, but in your java code your are type casting them as Textview, check the logs you may be getting some errors

Comment: No,there are no errors

Answer (score 0):

```
// in OnCreate in loginpage.java 

Button signNow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signnow);
mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton2);
mClickButton2.setOnClickListener(this);


// somewhere else in your code

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case  R.id.clickButton1: {
            // do something for button 1 click for example
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, signNow.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }

        case R.id.clickButton2: {
            // do something for button 2 click
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can u please say what changes should I do in my code.

Comment: You can start by changing the reference from TextView to Buttons. Then call the intent as you have already done

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Code

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class LoginPage : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page)

       //for sign button click listener
       val signNow = findViewById<View>(R.id.signnow) as Button
       signNow.setOnClickListener(this)

       //for login button click listener
       val login = findViewById<View>(R.id.login) as Button
       login.setOnClickListener(this)
   }

   override fun onClick(v: View) {
       when (v.id) {
           R.id.signnow -> {
               // Navigate to New User Register screen.
               startActivity(Intent(this, NewUserRegister::class.java))
           }

           R.id.login -> {
              // Navigate to Three Section screen.
              startActivity(Intent(this, ThreeSections::class.java))
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type cast of your `TextView` to `Button` in your **loginpage.java** code.

Change this

```
TextView login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);
```

To this

```
Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
```